# Scroll bar on <p> text

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm having this issue where all my texts wrapped in `<p>` or header tags, will result in an overflow scrollbar type display (and you'll have the ability to scroll it a little bit).  I have set `overflow` to none, further the height isn't even set.  Further the entire text is *mostly* shown (sometimes the scrolling will cut of the very bottom of text).

This issue occurs most prominently on this page: http://www.salonathon.org/meet-the-staff/ 
both on the headers and the description for each card.

I've messed around with setting a height and re-disabling the overflow on all the elements and this does not fix anything.

This is a WordPress site by the way.  (Further, this is my first foray into making themes for WordPress, so feel free to let me know if I'm doing something egregiously incorrectly.)

Here are the relevant bits of code:

---- The PHP ----

```
    <section class="header-margin staff-page">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php $args = array(
            'category_name' => 'staff',
            'meta_key'   => 'staff-order',
            'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <ul>
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <div>
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <h4 class="person"> <span class="name"> <?php the_title(); ?></span>  |   <?php the_excerpt(); ?></h4>
                                <p> <?php the_content(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </section>
</main>
```

---- The CSS ----

```
.header-margin{
    margin-top: 128px;
}

.staff-page {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1.page-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 40px;
}
    .staff-page > ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.person {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.name {
    font-family: 'salon6';
    font-size: 28px;
}

.staff-page > ul > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.staff-page > ul > li > div > img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    display: inline;
}

.staff-page > ul > li{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: row;

    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;

    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;

    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    padding: 20px;
}

.staff-page > ul > li > div:nth-child(2){
    padding-left: 25px;
    line-height: 15px;
    max-width:75%;
}
```

Comment: remove `line-height: 15px;` from `.staff-page > ul > li > div:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `line-height: 15px;` in below code is causing scroll bar's unwanted behavior.

**CSS:**

```
.staff-page > ul > li > div:nth-child(2){
    padding-left: 25px;
    line-height: 15px;
    max-width:75%;
}
```

to this:

```
.staff-page > ul > li > div:nth-child(2){
    padding-left: 25px;
    max-width:75%;
}
```

Also in **php** change this:

```
<p> <?php the_content(); ?></p>
```

to this:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

because of this rule:

```
media="all"
* {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

you can overwrite it

```
      media="all"
        * {
    //overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow: visible;
        }
```

or

```
.person, p
{
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
  .staff-page > ul > li > div:nth-child(2){
        padding-left: 25px;
        line-height: 15px;
        max-width:75%;
    }
```